# CSS Jumping animation timing

Tags: css

I want to create a jumping animation with CSS. Here is how I would like to split my animation:

1. Move up
2. Move down and start scaling up in the last half
3. Touch down at maximum scaling
4. Move up again scaling down in the first half

But what happens is the following:

1. Move up
2. Move down
3. Scale up
4. Scale down
5. Move up

   ```
   @keyframes jump {
     0% {
       transform: translateY(0);
     }

     10% {
       transform: translateY(-30%);
     }

     15% {
      transform: scale(1, 1);
     }

     20% {
      transform: translateY(0) scale(1.25, 0.75);
     }

     25% {
      transform: scale(1, 1);
     }

     30% {
      transform: translateY(-20%);
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: you need to chain all the transform together .. transform() scale() always together

Comment: Can you please be more precise ? If I put my `translateY(-30%)` with `scale(1, 1)`, the scale will start at the same time than the down movement ?

Comment: I made an edit to my answer. Not sure if this is what you meant... the jumps are not very high

Comment: Yep exactly! Thanks for help, I'll try to add a third jump to have a big one at start then medium then small with a bit of delay before restarting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This felt a bit more natural...

```css
@keyframes jump {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0) scale(1, 1);
  }

  15% {
    transform: translateY(-30%) scale(1, 1);
  }
  
  22% {
    transform: translateY(0) scale(1, 1);
  }

  25% {
    transform: translateY(10%) scale(1.25, 0.75);
  }

  30% {
    transform: translateY(-20%) scale(1, 1);
  }
  
  36% {
    transform: translateY(0) scale(1, 1);
  }

  40% {
    transform: translateY(5%) scale(1.1, 0.95);
  }
  
  44% {
    transform: translateY(-10%) scale(1, 1);
  }
  
  47% {
    transform: translateY(0) scale(1, 1);
  }
}

.item {
  width: 5rem;
  height: 5rem;
  margin: 2rem;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: rebeccapurple;
  animation: jump 3s infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="item"></div>
```